# How to enable GET request metric for S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to add a CloudWatch alarm for GET requests in an S3 bucket. In the Console, I went to Management -> Metrics for this bucket and checked the box for Request metrics (10) (paid feature). This also automatically checked the box for Data transfer metrics (6) (paid feature). I thought this would enable the GET request metric. Instead though only 5 request metrics and 3 data transfer metrics have appeared, and the GET request metric is not one of them. How do I fix this? I thought 16 new metrics should have appeared, but only 8 have.

Answer (score 2):

- Go to your S3 bucket
- Go to metrics tab
- Hit "View additional charts"
- Go to "Requests Metrics" tab
- Hit "Add filters"
- Make sure to check "This filter applies to all objects in the bucket"

After this you need to make some calls to your s3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively use S3 access logs to get the number of GET requests for your objects: [Using Amazon S3 access logs to identify requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-s3-access-logs-to-identify-requests.html).

Also note that some CloudWatch metrics only appear when there are actual data points. Operation-specific metrics (such as GetRequests) are reported only if there are requests of that type for your bucket or your filter.

Comment: This says there is a GetRequests metric: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html

Also the GetRequets metric is listed under the checkbox I selected. It's just not appearing for some reason.

Comment: I might be wrong, will check and correct my question. Give me a second.

Comment: You’re right. I fixed my answer, knowing that it doesn’t really answer your question, but it provides a workaround. Let me see, if I can find anything else.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful, but in this case I need to enable the GetRequests metric. It makes no sense to me why it isn't appearing.

Comment: It’s important to note that the metric only shows up in CloudWatch when there are actual data points. I.e. operation-specific metrics (such as GetRequests) are reported only if there are requests of that type for your bucket or your filter.

Comment: And also: Not every request necessarily leads to a datapoint. Have a look at the section “ Best-effort CloudWatch metrics delivery” here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/metrics-configurations.html